# Doomsday Fuel Challenge. Normal Linear algebra failing (Without using bifurcation of matrix like in Markov chain). 6/10 test cases are passing only

Tags: python, algorithm, markov-chains

**Problem Statement**
Commander Lambda has tasked you to help the scientists increase fuel creation efficiency by predicting the end state of a given ore sample. You have carefully studied the different structures that the ore can take and which transitions it undergoes. It appears that, while random, the probability of each structure transforming is fixed. That is, each time the ore is in 1 state, it has the same probabilities of entering the next state (which might be the same state).  You have recorded the observed transitions in a matrix. The others in the lab have hypothesized more exotic forms that the ore can become, but you haven't seen all of them.

Write a function solution(m) that takes an array of array of nonnegative ints representing how many times that state has gone to the next state and return an array of ints for each terminal state giving the exact probabilities of each terminal state, represented as the numerator for each state, then the denominator for all of them at the end and in simplest form. The matrix is at most 10 by 10. It is guaranteed that no matter which state the ore is in, there is a path from that state to a terminal state. That is, the processing will always eventually end in a stable state. The ore starts in state 0. The denominator will fit within a signed 32-bit integer during the calculation, as long as the fraction is simplified regularly.

```
For example, consider the matrix m:
[
  [0,1,0,0,0,1],  # s0, the initial state, goes to s1 and s5 with equal probability
  [4,0,0,3,2,0],  # s1 can become s0, s3, or s4, but with different probabilities
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s2 is terminal, and unreachable (never observed in practice)
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s3 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s4 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s5 is terminal
]
So, we can consider different paths to terminal states, such as:
s0 -> s1 -> s3
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s4
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s5
Tracing the probabilities of each, we find that
s2 has probability 0
s3 has probability 3/14
s4 has probability 1/7
s5 has probability 9/14
So, putting that together, and making a common denominator, gives an answer in the form of
[s2.numerator, s3.numerator, s4.numerator, s5.numerator, denominator] which is
[0, 3, 2, 9, 14].

Languages

To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java
To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py

Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution({{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}})
Output:
    [7, 6, 8, 21]

Input:
Solution.solution({{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}})
Output:
    [0, 3, 2, 9, 14]
```

## My approach

So I am constructing a simple matrix A where ith row represents the fraction/probability of state[i] being formed from other fuel states.
Like for {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
My matrix A will be -

````
```
    [1       -4/9    0    0     0    0]
    [-1/2      1     0    0     0    0]
    [0         0     1    0     0    0]
    [0       -3/9    0    1     0    0]
    [0       -2/9    0    0     1    0]
    [-1/2     0      0    0     0    1]



    B will be Transpose of. [s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5]
    C will be Transpose of [1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    
    So A x B=C
    B=A^-1 x C

```
````

To maintain fraction I have multiplied with LCM and determinant so that I dont lose value in float to fraction conversion later. So I make sure that the matrix I am inversion is of integers.

My Code is as below. Please tell me why would test case 1,2,3,8,9,10 pass but 4,5,6,7 fail

```
import numpy as np
import random

from fractions import Fraction
from numpy.linalg import inv

# mat= Matrix([ [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-1, 2)], [Fraction(-4, 9), Fraction(1,1)] ])
# x=mat.inv()


#samples
s1=[[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
s2=[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
s3=[[0,1,0],[2,0,0],[0,0,0]]



#only to generate random test cases
def generate(n):
    a=[]
    
    for i in range(n-1):
        x=[]
        partition=random.randint(0,7)
        for j in range(n):
            if partition<2:
                x.append(0)
            else:
                
                x.append(random.randint(1,300))
        a.append(x)
    x=[]
    for j in range(1):
        x.append(0)
    a.append(x)
    return a

#Main code here
def solution(s):
    sums=[]
    for i in s:
        sums.append(sum(i))
    n=len(s)
    A=[]
    for i in range(n):
        x=[]
        for j in range(n):
            x.append(Fraction(0,1))
        A.append(x)
    
    denominators=[]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                A[i][j]+=Fraction(1)
            if sums[j]!=0:
                #normalize to make probabilty
                A[i][j]=A[i][j]-(s[j][i]*Fraction(1,sums[j]))
                denominators.append(A[i][j].denominator)
                    
    A1=np.matrix(A,dtype='float')
    
    
    arr = np.array(denominators)    
    if(sum(arr)==0):
        LCM=1
    else:
        LCM = np.lcm.reduce(arr)
    LCM=max(1,LCM)
    #TO make sure that matrix has all integers. LCM will be adjusted later
    A1=A1*LCM
    det1=int(round(np.linalg.det(A1)))
    I1=inv(A1)
    I1=I1*det1
    denom=max(det1,1)
    
    
    
    I1=I1.tolist()
    

    target=[]
    denominators=[]
    for i in range(n):
        
        if sums[i]==0:
            target.append( Fraction(round(I1[i][0]))* Fraction(LCM,int(denom)))
            denominators.append(target[-1].denominator)

    
    arr = np.array(denominators)  
    if(sum(arr)==0):
        LCM1=1
    else:
        LCM1 = np.lcm.reduce(arr)
    LCM1 = np.lcm.reduce(arr)
    #LCM1=max(1,LCM1)
    
    #print("LCM=",LCM)
    for i in range(len(target)):
        target[i]*=Fraction(LCM1,1)
        target[i]=target[i].numerator

    target.append(LCM1)

    return target
```

Some other mathematics I used are as follow
```

````
    AxB=C
    (1/LCM)x(LCM x A)xB=C
    (LCM x A)x B=LCM x C
    THis was done so that A (now A1) always has integers
    A1 x B=LCM x C
    B= LCM x A1^-1 x C

```
````

Further determinant was multiplied to inverse and added in denominator to make matrix integer again so that fraction is recoverable.

Comment: Thanks to all those who tried. I figured out the issue. THe Determinant was growing too larger to inverse was becoming exponentially small. Morever whenI multiplied by determinant again, the number went too large and numpy expressed it in power form. So there was loss of information. Later while recovering and dividing this number never returned to original fraction format. Rather it turned into very large numerator and denominator. 
The solution was straight forward. Dont multiply or divide the matrix by constant and in the end  use limit_denomniator() of fractions to get result.

Comment: For the example matrix, how do you get 9 for s5?